# outofmemory android

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!

В приложении есть активити, которая вызывается несколько раз с разными картинками на заднем фоне:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

       mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        vek = intent.getIntExtra("vek", 0);

        switch (vek) {
            case 11:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back11);
                break;
            case 13:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back1113);
                break;
            case 16:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back16);
                break;
            case 17:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back17);
                break;
            case 18:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back18);
                break;
}
```

Примерно при 4 (когда как) запуске активити, происходит краш:

```
05-19 14:37:03.322    2153-2153/su.worldbest.bbdd E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14468)
            at su.worldbest.bbdd.Game.onCreate(Game.java:89)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Как исправить?

Comment: vek какой тип? если bitmap, то после того объект стал не нужен- вызывай recycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этот вопрос есть 2 ответа короткий и длинный.
Короткий - положите картинки для заднего фона в drawable-nodpi.

**UPD**. Если вкратце:

То что приложение перерестает падать если больше фоновые картинки ложить в `drawable-nodpi` это побочный эффект возникающий в результате того как андроид обращается с картинками. 
Есть 6 основных групп ресурсов для картинок:

- ldpi-120dpi-0.75x,
- mdpi-160dpi-1x,
- hdpi-240dpi-1.5x,
- xhdpi-320dpi-2x,
- xxhdpi-480dpi-3x,
- xxxhdpi-640dpi-4x

Также есть tvdpi-213dpi-1.33x, но он уже несколько неактуален.

Еще есть просто каталог `drawable` - он аналогичен `drawable-mdpi`, который считается базовым - 160dpi и множитель 1x. 1x означает что 1dp будет на экране занимать 1 пиксель. Например для xhdpi, 1dp будет занимать на экране 2 пикселя, соответственно плотность пикселей равна 160*2x=320, итд.

**Но зачем все это нужно?**

Предположим вы разрабатываете под xhdpi-320dpi под какой нибудь Nexus4. Вы нашли классную иконку для кнопки размером 100x100 пикселей, и на экране оно займет 50x50dp (множитель 2x) - если у него размеры `wrap_content` - что примерно физически равно 10мм - удобно попадать пальцем по кнопке и все влазит.

**Но тут возникает проблема:**

если бы Андроид ничего не делал то при запуске этого придожения на девайсе с крупными пикселами, например какой-то старый девайс с mdpi-160dpi вы увидете огромнейшие кнопки 20x20мм а на новых девайсах xxxhdpi-640dpi с высоким разрешением вы увидите малюсенькие кнопки по которым и пальцем тяжело попасть - 5x5мм.

Поэтому собственно и нужны эти 6 основных групп ресурсов. Вы готовите ресурса под какую-то одну плотность пикселей (**density**), например `xhdpi`, ложите эти ресурсы в каталог drawable-hdpi, а при запуске на другом `density` андроид при запуске возьмет эти картинки и изменит их размер.

Таким образом мы получаем следующее **преимущество**:

- на любом `density` картинки будут иметь один и тот же размер в dp, т.е. 
  физический размер. Другим словами если у вас на Nexus4 с `density` 320dpi картинка на экране занимает 10x10mm, то она будет иметь такой же размер на любых других девайсах с более высокой или низкой плотностью пикселей.

А также следующие **недостатки**:

- при масштабировании тратится дополнительная память что чревато `OutOfMemoryError`
- при масштабировании ухудшается качество изображения. Особенно это заметно при увеличении изображения.

От всего этого можно избавиться если вручную подготовить наборы ресурсов для всех основных групп.

А при чем же тут **drawable-nodpi** ?
Так вот, все вышесказанное не касается drawable-nodpi. Андроид не масштабирует картинки которые там находятся и отображает их как есть.

См. также:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118005/android-background-image-memory-usage

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Может, приложите ещё и короткое объяснение на русском? Для тех, кто не очень хорошо понимает иностранные языки.

Comment: @VladD обновил.

Comment: Ого! Класс, спасибо!